# Laravel 5.1 Class 'CreatePasswordResetsTable' Not Found

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I tried to run the command **php artisan migrate:refresh**, It throws the following error,

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>     Class 'CreatePasswordResetsTable' not found

I checked in DB, it has rows in the migration table. I truncated the table and re-run the command, It worked fine. I need to know why those rows are not deleted in migration table.

Comment: Did you delete the migration file `2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php` that comes with Laravel after running `php artisan migrate`?

Comment: When, I run the php artisan migrate:refresh, it rolled back all migrations and throwed above error.. I checked in db migrations table and I found the create password resets table exists.. So I manually truncated the table migration

Answer (score 5):

I get the same problem

is work for me

```
composer dumpautoload
```

Comment: Same here! I had deleted my migration files (having not used DB even once) but when I created new migration I got the above error. Doing `composer dumpautoload` solved it. Don't know why but it did. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In phpMyAdmin, manually delete the "migrations" table. Then re-run "php artisan migrate" in Terminal and it will re-create all of the tables for you.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally deleted my "create_users" and "create_passwords" table after executing "migrate" command. Executing the "php artisan migrate:refresh" gave me the following error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Class
>   'CreatePasswordResetsTable' not found

I solved the problem by manually deleting the "migrations" table through PHPMyAdmin. The command now doesn't throw any error.